# BizTalk error btm 1044 while Test Map using XML Instance

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I created a send and receive schema and generated a XML Instance for the Receive Schema.I created Map between send and receive schema. When I tried to Test the Map I used the Instance created with the Receive Schema as Input Instance. It throws an Error like

TestMap used the following file: as input to the map.error btm1044: Input validation error: The element is not declared.

Receive Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.myabc.org/biztalk/sample1/"     xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://www.myabc.org/biztalk/sample1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:element name="Employee">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element name="EmpDetails">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="Address">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="PinCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

The Input XML Instance used is

```
ns0:Employee xmlns:ns0="http://www.myabc.org/biztalk/sample1/">
- <EmpDetails>
  <Name>Name_0</Name> 
  <Age>Age_0</Age> 
  <Email>Email_0</Email> 
  <Phone>Phone_0</Phone> 
  </EmpDetails>
- <Address>
  <Street>Street_0</Street> 
  <City>City_0</City> 
  <PinCode>PinCode_0</PinCode> 
  </Address>
  </ns0:Employee>
```

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy/paste your XSD and XML files into Visual Studio and remove all of the "-" characters before the nodes, I get this:

```
Invoking component...
Validate Instance succeeded for schema test.xsd, file: <file:///C:\Temp\test.xml>.
Component invocation succeeded.
```

It seems to me the instance is valid.
The remark from Vikas Bhardway is a very good starting point here: try generating an instance and compare the two on nodes, namespaces, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Validate yr XML against the schema if it's not valid then generate a new instance and try with that again